# how to structure the array in java

Tags: java, arrays, structure

I am a newbie to java, so please forgive my ignorance. I am getting list of objects from amazon s3. I am now struggling to put it in an array that i can use.

I am getting the array but its not exactly how i want. The objectlist that i get looks like the following.

[image]

[image]

```
 ObjectListing listKey = s3client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(key).withDelimiter("/"));
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String obj2: listKey.getCommonPrefixes()){
            String test=obj2;
            keys.add(test);
        }
        for (S3ObjectSummary obj : listKey.getObjectSummaries()) {
            keys.add(obj.getKey());
        }
        return keys;
```

And the array i get through this code looks like this

[image]

this array is fine, but i also want to add the size and lastmodified of the objectsummary. But i should able to know that what size and lastmodified belongs to what key. I don't just want  the index but properties of one index or one object summary. some thing like the following,

[image]

I just edited the picture, it doesn't have to make perfect sense i am just trying to point out the structure i want. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: I missed it at first but now i have edited the question providing the code.

Comment: The last image looks like an `ArrayList<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` contains the path, the size and the last modified date which basically looks like a subset of `S3ObjectSummary`. What's the problem with this?

Comment: Thats a picture i provided to give the idea what i want :)

Comment: Yeah I got that and I meant that you basically have that already with the list of `S3ObjectSummary` elements. If you need something else then please describe (best with non-picture examples) what you mean with "I am getting the array but its not exactly how i want." - how do you want the array to look like?

Comment: Second last image shows the array i am getting right now, last image shows what i want.