# java arrays, array list, hashmaps and using them

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am a newbie with java and i am having huge trouble with arrays and hash maps.

Problem: I am getting objectListing from Amazon S3 service that includes two ArrayLists. (ObjectSummaries and commonPrefixes).

I am loop through them and add them into a List String. This is my code

```
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key_id, secret_access_key));

        ObjectListing listKey = s3client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(key).withDelimiter("/"));
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String obj2: listKey.getCommonPrefixes()){
            String test=obj2;
            keys.add(test);
        }
        for (S3ObjectSummary obj : listKey.getObjectSummaries()) {
            keys.add(obj.getKey());
        }
        return keys;

    } catch (AmazonServiceException x) {
        String errorCode = x.getErrorCode();
        if (!errorCode.equals("NoSuchKey")) {
            throw x;
        }
    }
```

This gives me the list with String keys. But now i want to get the size and Lastmodified of the key of the objectsummary as well. I should be able to know the size and lastmodifed of each key of objectsummary i add to the keys.

I don't know if i should use hashmap or what? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to structure the array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297177/how-to-structure-the-array-in-java)

Comment: You can use hashmap and use key as hashmap key and a data structure containing all of the data you want to store as value

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

1. Create a class with the required parameters

   ```
   public class MyObject {
       private String key;
       private int size;
       private Date lastModified;

       public MyObject() {}

       public MyObject(String key, int size, Date lastModified) {
            this.key = key;
            this.size = size;
            this.lastModified = lastModified;
       }

       /* Getters-Setters*/
   }
   ```
2. Create a list of `MyObject` instead of the `String`

   ```
   List<MyObject> myObj = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
   ```
3. Add values to the List

   ```
   for (S3ObjectSummary obj : listKey.getObjectSummaries()) {
       myObj.add(new MyObject(obj.getKey(), obj.getSize(), obj.getLastModified()));
   }
   ```

Comment: I want commonPrefixes and ObjectSummaries both in one arraylist which is String type. Otherwise i run into other problems and require more changes in other parts of the code. Is that possible? how can i do that?

Comment: In that case you can set the other two properties as `null`. For Example, `String test=obj2; myObj.add(new MyObject(obj2, null, null));`